# Collision in LibGDX

Tags: java, iterator, libgdx

I'm trying to get this game to work. It's not.

```
Iterator<Circle> iter = asteroids.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Circle asteroid = iter.next();
        asteroid.y -= speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (asteroid.y + asteroid.radius * 2 < 0)
            iter.remove();
        if (Intersector.overlapCircles(shipCir, asteroid) && alive) {
            iter.remove();
            alive = false;

        }
    }

    Iterator<Rectangle> iterB = bullets.iterator();
    while (iterB.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle bullet = iterB.next();
        bullet.y += 300 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (bullet.y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight())
            iterB.remove();

    }

    /*if (Intersector.overlapCircleRectangle(asteroid, bullet)) {
        // REMOVE OBJECT
    }                                                             
       */
```

The part that isn't working is the commented out section above. If you could tell me how to resolve that, it would be awesome. It won't let me access asteroid or bullet unless I'm inside the while loop and I don't know why.

UPDATE: Here is what I think you told me to try. It is still doing the same thing.

```
Iterator<Circle> iter = asteroids.iterator();
Iterator<Rectangle> iterB = bullets.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Circle asteroid = iter.next();
        asteroid.y -= speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (asteroid.y + asteroid.radius * 2 < 0)
            iter.remove();
        if (Intersector.overlapCircles(shipCir, asteroid) && alive) {
            iter.remove();
            alive = false;
            if (exploding) {
                exploding = false;
                explode.start();
            }
        }       
        while (iterB.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle bullet = iterB.next();
            bullet.y += 300 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if (bullet.y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight())
                iterB.remove();
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I'm getting an error occasionally on "iterB.remove();" and I don't know why.

Code:

```
Iterator<Circle> iter = asteroids.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Circle asteroid = iter.next();
        asteroid.y -= speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (asteroid.y + asteroid.radius * 2 < 0)
            iter.remove();
        if (Intersector.overlapCircles(shipCir, asteroid) && alive) {
            iter.remove();
            alive = false;
            if (!exploding) {
                exploding = true;
                explode.start();
            }
        }
        Iterator<Rectangle> iterB = bullets.iterator();
        while (iterB.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle bullet = iterB.next();
            bullet.y += 150 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

            if (Intersector.overlapCircleRectangle(asteroid, bullet)) {
                iterB.remove();
                iter.remove();

            }
            if (bullet.y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight())
                iterB.remove(); // ERROR HERE
        }
    }
```

Here's the error:

```
 Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.removeIndex(Array.java:216)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array$ArrayIterator.remove(Array.java:433)
at com.chanceleachman.space.Screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.chanceleachman.space.Space.render(Space.java:37)
at     com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:190)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:108)
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: The exact error said by Eclipse is, "asteroid cannot be resolved to a variable."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asteroid` and `bullet` variables are scoped to the while loop they are each defined in, and so cannot be used outside those scopes.  You should review Java [variable scoping](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/02/10/tutorial-java-scjp-10-variable-scope/).

You could fix the compiler error by hoisting the declaration of `bullet` and `asteroid` out of the while loops (i.e., `Circle asteroid; Rectangle bullet;`), but I don't think the resulting code would do what you intend (and it would crash where there are no bullets or no asteroids).

You need to consider the case where there are no bullets (or no asteroids), and you need to consider the case where there are multiple bullets and multiple asteroids.   You need to check  every bullet against every asteroid to see if they intersect.

Comment: Is there any easy way I could do this?

Comment: Yes, it should be easy.  Create a new loop over the bullets, and in the body of that loop, loop over each asteroid, and compare the bullet and asteroid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new at this and confused. Would you mind writing this code out for me and pasting it below. Thanks so much.

Comment: I've tried this but it still isn't working... The new code is at the top.

Comment: You're getting closer.  I don't think the error is "the same" now as it was before.  Please be precise in your questions and include the specific error message.  One problem I see is that you need to make a new Bullet iterator each time through the asteroid loop (move the declaration of iterB inside the while loop).

Comment: Actually, one more problem. I occasionally get a,  "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1" error. I'm not sure what it is caused by though. I tends to happen if I press the shoot repeatedly.

Comment: Read the documentation for Iterator.remove(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()

Comment: Perfect! Fixed that too! One last question, I promise. Your help has been outstanding! When the bullets are shot they tend to speed up and slow down. How might I be able to fix this? I think it would have something to do with everything being wrapped in, "while (iter.hasNext())."

Comment: Add a print statement outside the first loop, and another next to the `bullet.y += ...` line.  You'll see the bullet line is invoked too many times.  You want that once per bullet, not once per bullet per asteroid.

Comment: Once again, you've been an amazing help and I can't thank you more!

Comment: What PT was getting at is that you are incrementing bullet.y inside of the nested loop. That nested loop gets called for each asteroid - so the more asteroids you have, the faster the bullets are incremented. The answer here is to break the bullet.y increment out of that inner loop.